# MSM Will only load sub-site homepage, everything else 404's?

Tags: multi-site-manager, structure

I Have a MSM site setup, and am also using Structure.

The sub-site domains looks like: mymainsite.com/sub-site

The sub-site homepage loads just fine, but I cannot get to any pages after that - aka mymainsite.com/sub-site/anything gives me a 404.

I set up a template to try and see what's going on, and here's what I've found so far:

- Entries from the Main Site seem to load fine.
- Entries from the Sub Site 404
- The site="" parameter does not seem to work with the structure nav tag.

Here's what I have for testing:

```
<p>Site: {site_name}</p>
<p>Breadcrumbs: {exp:structure:breadcrumb}</p>
<p>This NAV: {exp:structure:nav site="sub_site"}</p>
<p>Main Site NAV: {exp:structure:nav site="main_site"}</p>
<p>Structure Page URL: {structure:page:url}</p>
<p>Structure Page URI: {structure:page:uri}</p>
<p>Structure Child IDs: {structure:child_ids}</p>
<p>Structure Entry ID: {structure:top:entry_id}</p>
<h2>TEST Entries:</h2><br>
{exp:channel:entries site="sub_site"}
<p>{title} - {page_url} - {entry_id}</p>
<p><a href="{page_uri}">{page_uri}</a></p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The output I get from http://mymainsite.com:

> Site: [Correct Site Name]
>   Breadcrumbs: [BLANK]
>   This NAV: [Correct, Nav for Main Site]
>   Main Site NAV: [Correct]
>   Structure Page URL: [BLANK]
>   Structure Page URI: [BLANK]
>   Structure Child IDs: [BLANK]
>   Structure Entry ID: [BLANK]
>   TEST Entries: [BLANK]

The output I get from http://mymainsite.com/sub-site:
*(404 template)*

> Site: [Correct Site Name]
>   Breadcrumbs: Home > Here (home link is correct)
>   This NAV: [Correct Nav for Sub Site, **BUT WRONG URLs, do not have /sub-site segment**]
>   Main Site NAV: [WRONG - shows nav for Sub Site]
>   Structure Page URL: [Correct]
>   Structure Page URI: / **(should be /sub-site ?)**
>   Structure Child IDs: [BLANK]
>   Structure Entry ID: [BLANK]
>   TEST Entries: Homepage (incorrect - url is to the main site's homepage)

The output I get from http://mymainsite.com/page:

> Site: [Correct Site Name]
>   Breadcrumbs: [BLANK]
>   This NAV: [Correct, Nav for Main Site]
>   Main Site NAV: [Correct]
>   Structure Page URL: [correct]
>   Structure Page URI: [correct]
>   Structure Child IDs: [BLANK]
>   Structure Entry ID: [correct]
>   TEST Entries: [BLANK]

The output I get from http://mymainsite.com/sub-site/page:
*(404 template)*

> Site: [WRONG - Main Site Name]
>   Breadcrumbs: [BLANK]
>   This NAV: [WRONG - Shows for Main Site]
>   Main Site NAV: [Correct]
>   Structure Page URL: [BLANK]
>   Structure Page URI: [BLANK]
>   Structure Child IDs: [BLANK]
>   Structure Entry ID: [BLANK]
>   TEST Entries: [Correct] - Lists all structure pages that exist under the Sub Site, correct {page_url} & {page_uri}, **BUT the links all 404**.

So the main issues I'm seeing is that the structure nav tag is not outputting the correct paths for the sub-site URLs as well. They're missing the /sub-site segment.

Any ideas what could possibly be going wrong here, or what I'm missing? I only have an htaccess file set up under the root, which contains:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

My directories are as follows:

Root -
 
    - Main Site (is in root)
    - images
    - skin
    - sub-site
    - sub-site
    - sub-site
System

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 1):

You are not directing sub-site requests to your `mymainsite.com/sub-site/index.php` file, so a URI like this: `mymainsite.com/sub-site/page` is being rendered by your main `mymainsite.com/index.php` file, so it's being loaded by your main site.

In your main `.htaccess` file, you have to direct sub-site requests to the right bootstrap `index.php`.

So, your main `.htaccess` could look something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sub-site [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !sub-site/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub-site/index.php [L]

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and you could add an `.htaccess` file to your sub-site folder that removes the `index.php`:

```
# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule sub-site/index\.php/*(.*) sub-site/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

This is example is very untested, and I'm kinda asleep right now so my `.htaccess` foo is weak, but you get the point. If you monkey with it a bit (or Google around for the right rules) you should get it up and running.

Also, for your `mymainsite.com/sub-site` results, this part:

```
This NAV: [Correct Nav for Sub Site, BUT WRONG URLs, do not have /sub-site segment]
```

You must not have your settings correct in your sub-site `index.php` file. Review the MSM settings you must set in your sub-site `index.php` files and that should fix it:

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/msm/overview.html

So something like this should live near the top of `sub-site/index.php`

```
$assign_to_config['site_name'] = 'sub_site_shortname';
$assign_to_config['cp_url']    = 'http://mymainsite.com/system';
$assign_to_config['site_url']  = 'http://mymainsite.com/sub-site';

$system_path = '../system/';
```

I'm pretty out of it right now but this should get you pointed in the right direction. I haven't worked an MSM installation that used sub-folders instead of separate domains or sub-domains in a long time so I don't have any `.htaccess` files I can reference at hand, but your `.htaccess` file setup is a prime culprit of the misbehavior.

Comment: Thank you, there were a few issues going on but this lead me down the right path... appreciate the help! All working now :)